# AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation

Tags: python, module, speech-recognition, pyaudio, speech

I'am codding a personal assistan but when I use speec_recognizer on my project I am getting this warning "AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation" and then I uploaded this module by pip but I am getting same warning when I run  code.

Comment: try 'python -m pip install PyAudio'

Comment: I tried to do that but it's not working.

Comment: with -m? python -m pip?